# How to convert macOS Extended Journaled to APFS?

Tags: macos, partition, mojave, apfs, disk-volume

My Macintosh HD is running Sierra from which partition for Mojave was made which doesn’t has APFS option.

Installed Mojave 10.14.2 on a MacBook Pro mid 2012 which has HDD and volume  formatted in macOS Extended Journaled.

Tried to install Xcode 10.2 on Mojave 10.14.2 and got error "this version of Xcode requires Mojave 10.14.3 or later"

Then downloaded [macOS Mojave 10.14.4 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1996?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), tried to install it and I got an error:

[image]

How to convert the Mojave volume from macOS Extended Journaled to APFS even when convert to APFS option is dimmed in Disk Utility:

[image]

Comment: were you successful installing Mojave?  What system did you have before installing Mojave?

Comment: Im dual booting Mojave and Sierra. Sierra is the initial OS form which partition for majoave was made ,yes mojave successfully installed

Answer (score 4):

[This site](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/upgrade-mac-apfs-after-high-sierra/) has instructions on how to convert your drive to APFS.

1. Restart the Mac into Recovery Mode.
2. Launch Disk utility.
3. Click-select your named boot volume. (Not the physical drive above it.)
4. In the Disk Utility Edit menu, select “Convert to APFS

More detailed instructions are given in the link above.

Comment: I'm on Mojave 10.14.1 and booted into recovery mode. I don't even see the "Convert to APFS" option under Edit menu, and the boot volume is grayed out.

Comment: same. would like to know what the steps are if you are running mojave

Answer (score 3):

How to convert your drive to APFS:

- Restart the Mac into Recovery Mode.
- Launch Disk utility.
- Click-select your named boot volume. (Not the physical drive above it.)
- Click the "Unmount" button. <- This enables "Convert to APFS"!
- Select "Convert to APFS" from the Edit menu.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to convert an macOS Extended Journaled drive to APFS without losing data.

The only way I was able to install a newer operating system was to backup the drive with time machine, fresh install the new operating system (catalina), migrate data from the time machine backup after install.